# SwiftUI allow Toggle only on certain conditions

Tags: swift, swiftui

My app has paid features. I have a Toggle that the user can switch. If the user has not paid, then when the user tries to toggle the Toggle a sheet should be brought up (and the toggle should not be activated). If the user has paid, then the toggle can be toggled on and off without problems.

I can't understand how a simple struct (`PaidFeature`) can have access to an observable object (`Model`). How do I code that in SwiftUI?

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var hasUserPaid: Bool = false
}

struct PaidFeature {
    var isEnabled = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var feature = PaidFeature()
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model

    
    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: self.$feature.isEnabled) {
            Text("Hello, World!")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Xcode 12, you can listen for changes of the toggle button using `.onChange` modifier, and whenever user toggles the button, you can toggle it back to the last state, and instead show a `purchase this` sheet if the user is not a premium user.

```
        .onChange(self.feature.isEnabled) { isEnabled in
                    if isEnabled && shouldShowPurchaseSheet {
                        // toggle back if you want the button to go to the inactive state
                        // show the sheet
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `disabled` modifier to the `Toggle`.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var feature = PaidFeature()
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model

    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: self.$feature.isEnabled) {
            Text("Hello, World!")
        }.disabled(!model.hasUserPaid)
    }
}
```

Comment: `disabled` completely disables the Toggle. Instead, I would like to bring up a "Purchase this" sheet if the user tries to switch on the toggle.

Answer (score 1):

I assume it should be as

```
var body: some View {
    Toggle(isOn: self.$feature.isEnabled) {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
    .disabled(!model.hasUserPaid)     // << here !!
}
```

**Update:** demo of alternate variant with showing sheet. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

For simplicity all of demo all states are kept in view

```
struct DemoView: View {
    @State private var feature = false
    @State private var paid = false
    @State private var showPurchase = false

    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $feature) {
            Text("Hello, World!")
        }
        .allowsHitTesting(paid)
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
            if !self.paid {
                self.showPurchase = true
            }
        })
        .sheet(isPresented: $showPurchase) {
            Text("Purchase this")
                .onDisappear {
                    self.paid = true
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `disabled` completely disables the Toggle. Instead, I would like to bring up a "Purchase this" sheet if the user tries to switch on the toggle.

Comment: Thank you, I'd only say that the Toggle shouldn't be toggled if the sheet is presented. I'm manually setting `self.feature = false` along with `self.showPurchase = true` to force the "untoggle" action but it looks like something overrides it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use condition in body View

```swift
if self.model.hasUserPaid == true {
   Toggle(isOn: self.$feature.isEnabled)) {
      Text("Hello, World!")
   }
} else {
   Toggle(isOn: .constant({default Bool})) {
      Text("Hello, World!")
   }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `if self.model.hasUserPaid == true { ... }` you can `if self.model.hasUserPaid { ... }`